# Django ModelForm with field overwrite does not post data

Tags: django, django-forms

So, I have the following form:

```
class DesignItemForm (forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(DesignItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    CHOICES=[(i,i) for i in range(MAX_DESIGN_ITEM_QUANTITY)]
    self.fields['quantity'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)    
class Meta:
    model = DesignItem
    fields = ('quantity','trackable',)
```

My view:

```
d = Design.object.get(slug=fromInput)
....
DesignItemInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Design, DesignItem, fk_name="design", form=DesignItemForm,)

    if request.method == "POST":
    formset = DesignItemInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=d)
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save() 
DesignItemInlineFormSet(instance=d)
```

As you can tell, in my form, I overwrote the quantity field to be a drop down instead of an integer field.

For some reason, when I submit the form, the data is not updated in the database. However, if I change the form to the following, it works (of course, it doesn't have the dropdowns I want, but it posts to the db). Why is this, and how do I fix it?

```
class DesignItemForm (forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(DesignItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # CHOICES=[(i,i) for i in range(MAX_DESIGN_ITEM_QUANTITY)]
    # self.fields['quantity'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)  
class Meta:
    model = DesignItem
    fields = ('quantity','trackable',)
```

EDIT: Here is the DesignItem model:

```
class DesignItem(models.Model):
"""Specifies how many of an item are in a design."""
design = models.ForeignKey(Design, related_name="items")
quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
trackable = models.ForeignKey(Trackable, related_name="used")
```

Comment: I can't spot any problems in the code you've posted. Can you show us your `DesignItem` model and how you are defining `DesignInlineFormSet`?

Comment: Okay, posted, and updated the view code to show the DesignItemInlineFormset definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried just overriding the widget instead of the whole field?

i guess you want a [select widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#select)

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(DesignItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    CHOICES=[(i,i) for i in range(MAX_DESIGN_ITEM_QUANTITY)]
    self.fields['quantity'].widget = forms.Select(choices=CHOICES)
```

Comment: Yes, and I didn't have any luck populating the select box with values. If you have any sample code, I'd be willing to try again.

Comment: Thanks -- I will give this a try and report back.